# Sum in the matrix (moving down and to the right in the matrix) Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Help me to calculate max sum in matrix. I have to find the path that maximizes the sum of the numbers from fields you visit. You can move down or right. Start at the upper left corner, end at the down right corner. I haven't been able to do this on my own for a few days.

Constraints:

```
0 < n <= 100
```

Code , I have : https://yadi.sk/d/VXZMw1l_PwHYow

```
Sample Input:

3            # n Number of cols and rows
10 15 9
12 3 6
20 1 17 

Sample Output:

60
```

[image]

Comment: Please, add your code to question.

Comment: I added to cloud.

Comment: How do you determine the path?

Comment: You should try with [numpy](https://numpy.org/). When adding code, please write it here as text, not as a link to somewhere.

Comment: It is asking me to install stuff.

Comment: I can't solve the task. I need a solution with an explanation.

Comment: You can't use libraries @itaishz

Comment: Try this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-path-sum-matrix/

Comment: @ericl16384 Now you don't need to install.

Comment: @forgetso I tried before I go to the stackoverflow.

Comment: @Chris Charley No, you can't use any not pre-installed libraries.( for example you can use : random , collections.. )

Comment: Which of these rules applies? (1) You can make n down moves followed by n right moves or n right moves followed by n down moves. (2) You must make a total of n down moves and n right moves, but you can do them in any order. (I assume the goal is to choose the moves that maximize the sum along the path you follow.)

Comment: @MatthiasFripp I have to find the path that maximizes the sum of the numbers from fields you visit.

Comment: @ChrisCharley here's the first hint. 4!/(2! * 2!) = 6 . I didn't know it. I drew graphs and count arrows.

Comment: I think that [multiset permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+find+multiset) gives the possible paths.

Comment: @Michaelan But what are the rules about the path you can follow? Can you go right, down, down, right?

Comment: This is a shortest-path problem, except you want to find the longest path instead. Each cell is a node and there are one-way edges connecting neighbors that are to the right or below each other. The length/cost of each edge is given by the number in the cell at the end of that edge. This may help: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-path-for-directed-acyclic-graphs/ (Note, shortest path algorithms should work fine, with just a reversal of the goal. Or you can make yours a true shortest path problem by converting all cells to 1000-cell.)

Comment: For others commenting here, @Michaelan found a simple answer based on dynamic programming at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-path-in-a-matrix-from-top-left-to-bottom-right/ . However, his self-answer here has been deleted for some reason.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp Wow, that is (geeksforgeeks) short. Wonder how to convert to python?

Comment: There's a Python implementation about halfway down the page. This problem is actually a great match for dynamic programming. The idea of their algorithm is just to start at the top left corner, then work across and down, and assign the highest value of any path to each cell. It's easy to do, because for any individual cell the best value is the max of the cell above or to the left, plus the value of this cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `A` your matrix, this sum is equal to the first column minus the last row without the first element:

```
S = A[:, 0].sum() + A [-1, 1:].sum()
```

Comment: You can move down or right, for example, you start and go to the right instead of down and check if it more.

Comment: only for this particular case,suppose the first row have a very large value then it will give wrong answer

Comment: Sorry, I did misread your question and will refine it later. There is a solution by looking at all partitions of the number of rows and columns.